# How to setup a new ubuntu server with an old django code which already has its migration files?

Tags: django, python-2.7, nginx, django-migrations, ubuntu-server

I have a completely working in-production Django code running on ubuntu server. For some reasons, I have to move all that code to a new server. I have managed with the new ec2 instance n all, and have git cloned my repo to this server. What to do now with the unapplied changes/migrations(Its showing few changes even though I havent changed anything on the old code)? Do I have to delete all migrations and recreate them all? Or just run python makemigrations with the old code. Running this is showing things like:

```
Did you rename schoolpoint.near_distance_points to schoolpoint.first_born_child_points (a IntegerField)? [y/N] y
Did you rename schoolmodel.is_hostel to schoolmodel.collab (a BooleanField)? [y/N]

Did you rename schoolmodel.monthly_fee to schoolmodel.featured_view_count (a IntegerField)? [y/N] y
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'receipt_id' to formreceiptmodel without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

Many of these are occurring. Shall I go find them manually from the code whether it is changed or not?

Comment: No why would you do any of this? You don't need to either delete migrations nor make new ones. If the new server is pointing at the same database as before you shouldn't need to do anything; if it's a new database then of course you should run all the migrations to set up the tables.

Comment: there is no database linked currently. I have to loaddata from the dump file i have created of the older server.

The old code already has all the migrations, and i have made no direct change on the models.py. So I am not able to understand why is it demanding to make migrations at the first place.

Comment: Well now I understand even less. Obviously you will need to link your new server with a database. And if you have dumped the data from the old db, just load it into the new one and then there's nothing else to do.

Comment: okay I will now link my database. But how to undo the damage I did by running python manage.py migrate !?

Comment: It seems that you have cloned the code but haven't migrated database.

Comment: There is no damage by python manage.py migrate as you will link your old database.

Comment: @AshutoshKumar , the code also has the migrations along with it. right?